# Panic runtime error while running Hello Couchbase application

Tags: go, couchbase

Installed go SDK 1.6 following the instructions given here:
https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/current/start-using-sdk.html
Created Hello Couchbase application as listed on the above page. While running the application, the program panics at the line :slight_smile:
for rows.Next(&row) {
and produces the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x12d66b2]
```

Go version prints the following: go version go1.12.9 darwin/amd64
macOS version 10.14.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once you’ve installed the SDK you can run this simple code snippet
>   showcasing some of its features.
>
> Error checking has been omitted for brevity.
>
> https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/current/start-using-sdk.html

---

In Go, always check for errors. If you check for errors, what errors occur?

The error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

often indicates that an error was ignored.

Comment: changed line: 
rows, _ := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(query, []interface{}{"African Swallows"})
to
rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(query, []interface{}{"African Swallows"})
to handle error. Also changed bucketname in line below to actual name of the bucket:
query := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM bucketname WHERE $1 IN interests") .

original example code is here:  https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/current/start-using-sdk.html